# A family of integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Our textbooks says "We infer from Proposition 23 of the preceding chapter that if $F$ is a family of functions on E that is uniformly integrable and tight over E, then each function in F is integrable over E."

Proposition 23:

> Let f be a measurable funciton on E. If f is integrable over E, then for each $\epsilon < 0$, there is a $\delta < 0$ for which
>
> if $A \subset E$ is measurable and $m(A)<\delta$, then $\int_A |f| < \epsilon$.
>
> Conversely, in the case $m(E)<\infty$, if for each $\epsilon < 0$, there is a $\delta < 0$ for which (26) [the above] holds, then f is integrable over E.

What I don't understand is...if there is a family of functions that is uniformly integrable, then how is it possible for one of the functions in that family to $*not*$ be integrable? Why do we need tightness to conclude that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like a not so well written paragraph in a text.

Comment: I agree that it is not very well written. The definition of "uniformly integrable family" should require that every single member of the family is integrable. Otherwise the language gets confusing.

Comment: It actually seems to follow from Proposition 25, not 23.

Answer (score 0):

Royden & Fitzpatrick defines uniform integrability for a collection of measurable functions. A uniformly integrable function (i.e. the collection of measurable functions that consist of a single function) fails to be integrable precisely when its domain has unbounded measure. Also see [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334344/collection-is-uniformly-integrable-but-individual-is-not-integrable/2004384#2004384).